# Increase MRU size of Windows emoji keyboard

Tags: windows-11, emoji, emoji-keyboard

I am a big user of emoji. When I open it, it shows the recently used emoji in the first 2 lines. But I prefer to see 4-5 lines worth of recent emoji.

Is it possible to as many as 24-30 MRU emoji?

[image]

Comment: No, what you describe would require the application to offer this option, and it doesn’t

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe some secret registry setting?

Comment: The secret registry setting does not exist